# How to run qmake files?

Tags: qmake

I'm new to Linux and have just started using Ubuntu.

I'm trying to install QtScript Generator. Here is what it's README says:

Step 1:

> Build the generator: cd path/to/this/project/generator, qmake && make

Done.

Step 2:

> Run the generator (without arguments)
>      This will generate C++ files in path/to/this/project/generated_cpp
>      and documentation in path/to/this/project/doc

How do I run the generator file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After running `make`, an executable called `generator` is created inside the source directory (the one you are in at this point). To execute it, type

```
./generator
```

The `./` is necessary because the shell by default looks for executables only in directories found in the `$PATH` environment variable. The `./` tells it to look inside the current directory.